# checking if the submit button was pressed in php

Tags: php, forms

I have been tackling this problem for some time and have spent a lot of time searching for a solution.
When calling a function, I would like to know if the the submit button of the form was pressed.

I found some similar situations that called for using  isset(). I don't make it to the "else" part in this code. 
I also followed the suggestion of using array_key_exists() and run into the same problem.

```
        if(!isset($_POST['subpic'])) {
        $pic .= "<form name=\"bg\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\" action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>
                        <p><input type=\"file\" name=\"bgpic\"></p>
                        <p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"subpic\" value=\"Submit\"></p>
                    </form>";
    }else{
            $pic .= "<p>Do something esle</p>";
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is the error? How do you check that form is submitted?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to detect if a form was submitted and the button is you way of tracking this. 

What do you want to happen if the form is submitted by the user pressing ENTER without clicking the button?

If you are trying to detect if a specific form is being submitted have you considered a hidden field with a form name/id?

Comment: What I am trying to do is check what to do next. If the submit button has not yet been pressed, display the form. If the submit has been pressed, use further code to check if the file is uploaded and move the move to its final destination. I apologize for being vague. This is my first post and I am not very polished yet.